# How to use new keyword in typescript with old school class declaration function+prototype?

Tags: typescript

I have some super old javascript code that for time reason don't want to fully migrate to TS and am facing one issue.

I get the error below

```
TS7009: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

when trying to use

```
// This file is MagicText.ts

import TextAnimation from './TextAnimation';

new TextAnimation(geometry);
```

The other file TextAnimation.ts contains an old school JS class declaration with constructor function + prototype:

```
export default function TextAnimation(this: any, textGeometry: any): typeof TextAnimation.prototype {
// some code here
}
TextAnimation.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
TextAnimation.prototype.constructor = TextAnimation;
```

How can I fix this error without ignoring with ts-ignore ?
How can I declare that this function actually is a constructor and not a normal function

I want to use the old style class declaration correctly with typescript and not convert to export default class for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `declare class TextAnimation`. Since `declare` is used, this class will not appear in the compiled js code, however ts will still assume that it exists.

```
declare class TextAnimation {
  public readonly textGeometry: any;
  constructor(textGeometry: any);
}

function TextAnimation(this: any, textGeometry: any) {
  this.textGeometry = textGeometry;
}

export default TextAnimation;
TextAnimation.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
TextAnimation.prototype.constructor = TextAnimation;
```

---

However, ts will continue to assume that there is not only a class, but also a function, and they are combined into one object. And so that ts knows that calling this function will not return your class, but an error will thrown (since `this` will be undefined), you can describe result of function as `never`:

```
function TextAnimation(this: any, textGeometry: any): never;
function TextAnimation(this: any, textGeometry: any) {
  this.textGeometry = textGeometry;
}
```

Comment: I found this incredibly useful.  most of the responses I've found online have just referred me to classes or something completely irrelevant.  thank you.